# How I can prepend an element after each child in a react jsx render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following code:

```
class MessageList extends Component {

  render () {
    return (
      <ul>
        {
          this.props.messages.map((message) => {
            return <Message key={message.id} message={message} />
          })
        }
        {
          this.props.replied_messages.map((message) => {
            return <Message key={message.id} message={message} />
          })
        }
      </ul>
    )
  }

}
```

I want to add `this.props.replied_messages.map` after each child on `this.props.messages.map`.

Example data:

```
let initialState = {
  messages: [
    {
      id: 0,
      timestamp: 1464092864076,
      text: 'holas'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      timestamp: 1464125678372,
      text: 'other comment'
    }
  ],
  replied_messages: [
    {
      id: 0,
      message_replied_id: 0,
      timestamp: 1464092864076,
      text: 'eyyy'
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      message_replied_id: 0,
      timestamp: 1464125851108,
      text: 'a reply'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      message_replied_id: 1,
      timestamp: 1464125909151,
      text: 'other comment reply'
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're saying you want the entire `replied_messages` array to render after every item in `messages`? Or there's some correlation between items in `messages` and `replied_messages`? If so, what?

Comment: Well after doing what you describe I want to add a conditional, if the replied messages have associated the id of the current child in the loop is showed.

Comment: So you're saying that some items in `replied_messages` have the same `id` as items in `messages`, and you want them to appear after each other? Can you show some example data and how you want it to be rendered?

Comment: here you go http://pastebin.com/raw/2RMtyTY1

Comment: Please post that in your question.

Comment: "*prepend* an element *after* each child"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to add `this.props.replied_messages.map` after each child on
>   `this.props.messages.map`.

What it sounds like you want to do is render a threaded message list. If you want to render a flat list of `<Message>` components where all replies follow their parent message, you could do this with a nested map: `map` over the `messages`, then get all replies to that message using a `filter` on the `replied_messages`, then combine both (message + replies for that message) into an array and `map` the array to `<Message>` components.

```
<ul>
  { this.props.messages.map(message =>
    [
      message, 
      ...this.props.replied_messages.filter(reply => reply.message_replied_id == message.id)
    ].map(message => <Message key={message.id + "_" + message.message_replied_id} message={message}/>)
  ) }
</ul>
```

[Example in CodePen.](http://codepen.io/abeall/pen/YWKXBN?editors=0010)

(Note that since your `messages` and `replied_messages` have duplicate `id` values, I had to make the `key` based on both. Preferably you would *not* have duplicate ids like this.)

---

But if I were you I would just build a threaded message list *first*, and render a hierarchical component tree with replies as *children* of their parent message. For example, you can build the threaded messages from your two arrays like this:

```
function messagesToThreads(messages, replied_messages) {
  return messages.map(message => {
    return {
      message,
      replies: replied_messages.filter(reply => reply.message_replied_id == message.id)
    }
  });
}
```

And render *nested* `<Message>` items to create a hierarchical list:

```
  <ul>
    { messagesToThreads(this.props.messages, this.props.replied_messages).map(thread =>
      <Message key={thread.message.id} message={thread.message}>
        { thread.replies.map(reply => <Message key={reply.id} message={reply} />) } 
      </Message>
    ) }
  </ul>
```

[Example in CodePen.](http://codepen.io/abeall/pen/jrNPKp?editors=0010)

Comment: I used the second example and now works really well.